# Chebyshev's inequality to find minimum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, variance

I'm trying to solve this:
In a factory, 5% of scrows are faulty (independently).

Each shipment contains 10K of scrows, and is eligible for a refund in case more than r scrows are faulty.
Using Chebyshev's inequality, find the minimum value of r so that no more than 1% of shipments will be eligible for a refund.

So if X is the number of faulty scrows, then X~$B(10K, \frac {5} {100})$.
It means $\mathbb E(X)=500$ and $var(X)=475$.

Now I'm not sure how to use chebyshev's inequality. Will $\mathbb P(|X-\mathbb E(X)|\geq r+1)$ give me what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a scrow?

Comment: @markvs - [apparently](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100449549) an obsolete form of scroll

Comment: It seems you are indeed expected to use Chebyshev's inequality to find the minimum $r$ giving  $\mathbb P(|X-\mathbb E(X)|\geq r+1)\le 0.01$.  It will be substantially   higher than using a one-tailed binomial or normal approximation.

Comment: @Henry - So to find it I need to solve the right inequality of $\mathbb P(|X- \mathbb E(X)| \geq r+1) \leq \frac {var(X)} {(r+1)^2} \leq 0.01$ ?

Comment: Something like that, except you may then need to add $\mathbb E[X]$.

Comment: @Henry: I see. So what exactly does the factory produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted this using Chebyshev's inequality, but didn't get the right answer. The right answer is $551$. I calculated it using the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

$$\text{Pr}(X \leq k) =  \sum_{i=0}^\text{floor(k)} \frac {n! \space p^i (1-p)^{n-i}}{i!(n-i)!}$$
$$\text{Pr}(X \leq r) =  \sum_{i=0}^\text{floor(r)} \frac {(10,000)! \space (0.05)^i (0.95)^{(10,000-i)}}{i!(10,000-i)!}$$
I computed this answer with [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20i%3D0%20to%20551%20of%20%28%2810%2C000%21%29%280.05%5Ei%29%280.95%5E%2810%2C000-i%29%29%2F%28%28i%21%29%28%2810000-i%29%21%29%29) (in case it doesn't load, there's a picture at the end of this answer):

$\text{Pr}(X \leq r) > 0.99$ when $r$ is $551$.

(and it's $<0.99$ for $r=550$ and lower)

---

By a quick sanity check, we can already see that r will be at least $500$ (because on average, an order of $10,000$ screws will contain $5$% or $500$ faulty screws. Half (50%) of the orders will have more, half (50%) will have less; the problem asks for 99% to have less than r faulty screws).

Chebyshev's Inequality:
$$P(|X-\mathbb E(X)|\geq a) \leq \frac {\text{Var}(X)}{a^2}$$

Of course, this will become (for the random variable $X$, $0 \leq X \leq 10,000$):

$$P(|X-500|\geq a) \leq \frac {\text{Var}(X)}{a^2}$$

We must compute $\text{Var}(X)$. This is easy, since we know each screw independently has a $5$% chance of being defective. In a form similar to the pythagorean theorem, the variance of a sum of random variables is the sum of their variances! So, find $\text{Var}(X)$ like so:

$$\text{Var}(\text{probability of defects in just one screw})=(\sum_i {p_ix^2_i}) - \mu^2$$
$$=(0.05)(1^2)+(0.95)(0^2) - (0.05^2)$$
$$=0.05-0.05^2=0.0475$$
Now, we multiply the variance of $r$($1$ screw) by $10,000$ to find the variance of $10,000$ screws:
$$\text{Var}(X) = (0.0475)(10,000)=475 \text{ screws}^2$$

We would like the probability of $X$ being greater than $500$ to be less than or equal to $1$%. So,

$$\frac {\text{Var}(X)}{a^2} = 1\text{%} = 0.01$$

$$\frac {475}{a^2}=0.01$$
$$47,500=a^2$$
$$a=50\sqrt {19} \approxeq 217.9$$
**EDIT:** I realize now what the error was in my thinking: $a$ represents the distance from the mean that the random variable has a chance of being. I only care about the chance of the random variable being *more* than its mean, not less, so the number found by this method will be larger than necessary, but probably not exactly twice as large as necessary. Since the floor of $a$ is $217$, and $a$ is a distance from the mean ($500$), this means that Chebyshev's inequality gives:
$$r \leq 717$$

which isn't exactly satisfying.

[image: Answer to binomial equation with wolframalpha.com]

Comment: $551$ is correct for this binomial distribution, and a normal approximation would give a similar number.  $717.9$ is  what I found using Chebyshev's inequality and is what led to my earlier comment "It will be substantially higher than using a one-tailed binomial or normal approximation."

Comment: I wasn't able to comment on this earlier but youv'e helped me a lot here! thanks!